# How to set image dimensions through javascript? (SSL logo served through JS, no dimensions)

Tags: javascript, html, image, ssl

Situation: an EV-SSL logo is served through javascript - it MUST be served through the script, for authentication purposes.

Problem: the script does not specify image dimensions. This fails with many page-speed optimization checkers.

Question: what is the proper syntax to set the image dimensions (height=100, width=85) for an image served through javascript?

I've tried the example below, but it's NOT working:

```
<script>COT("https://www.mywebsite.com/system-images/cot_evssl.gif", "width=100", "height=85","SC2","none");</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the script that serves the EV-SSL logo? FYI the page-speed optimization checkers are probably focusing on the initial page load, when an image with no dimensions slows things down. In your case since the image is written in by a javascript, it'll always be slower than a normal image (even if only by a tiny bit). You can surround it with some jQuery to make sure it waits until the document is ready, but it'll still take a split second.

Comment: Can you use JQuery? $("yourSelector").on("load", function() {$("yourSelector").css({"height":100, "width":85})}) where yourSelector is the image.

Comment: Here's the contents of "comodo_cot.js":

http://pastebin.com/714siGxs

Comment: I think I see what you're saying: you include that script on your page, and when it runs, it prints the image, but it leaves out the dimensions. Is that correct? If so I'm not sure if you'll ever be able to make their system print it with dimensions. And anything you do to get the dimensions will have to be after it's been printed on your page. So in terms of speeding things up, it'll be useless. The browser will already have determined the dimensions the moment the image was printed.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new image DOM element, put the url received on the script as the src, and get the dimensions from the img tag, kinda like this:

```
function getDimenions(imgURL) {
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = imgURL;
   img.onLoad = function(){
     console.log(this.height);
     console.log(this.width);
   }
 }
```

you will have to work around the fact that loading the image works asynchronously, but that's pretty much the gist.

Comment: I know the dimensions, they don't change - it's always 100x85px, so there's no need to read them dynamically.

The .GIF file is on my server, but the SSL provider's (Comodo) Javascript adds the overlay that shows the SSL info.

Comment: I know the dimensions, they don't change - it's always 100x85px, so there's no need to read them dynamically.

The .GIF file is on my server, but the SSL provider's (Comodo) Javascript adds the overlay that shows the SSL info.

The issue is that I need to **add** the dimensions to the final HTML rendering, so it shows up as:

    <img src="https://www.mysite.com/system-images/cot_evssl.gif" height="100" width="85">